# What published module is described in this article by The Alexandrian?

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification

In [this article](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/4147/roleplaying-games/dont-prep-plots), the blogger The Alexandrian describes the plot of a published adventure, swapping the original names and locations with ones of his own device.

> Pursuing the villains who escaped during last week’s session, the PCs will get on a ship bound for the port city of Tharsis. On their voyage they will spot a derelict. They will board the derelict and discover that one of the villains has transformed into a monster and killed the entire crew… except for one lone survivor. They will fight the monster and rescue the survivor. While they’re fighting the monster, the derelict will have floated into the territorial waters of Tharsis. They will be intercepted by a fleet of Tharsian ships. Once their tale is told, they will be greeted in Tharsis as heroes for their daring rescue of the derelict. Following a clue given by the survivor of the derelict, they will climb Mt. Tharsis and reach the Temple of Olympus. They can then wander around the temple asking questions. This will accomplish nothing, but when they reach the central sanctuary of the temple the villains will attempt to assassinate them. The assassination attempt goes awry, and the magical idol at the center of the temple is destroyed. Unfortuntely, this idol is the only thing holding the temple to the side of the mountain — without it the entire temple begins sliding down the mountain as the battle continues to rage between the PCs and villains!

Which adventure is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct module, but it has a few of the same details you describe.  "Night of the Shark" is the 2nd part of a Monstrous compendium Trilogy dealing with the Sauhaugin.  The first part is called "Evil Tide" and the last one is called "Sea of Blood".  These three modules go along with a Monstrous Arcana called the "See Devils".  They were all written for 2nd Edition.

I was a player in the campaign and not the DM so didn't actually read the module.  When I read the synopsis of the question I immediately thought of this adventure we went on.

In our adventure our ship came upon a derelict vessel.  While we were exploring the vessel it got pulled to a different location.  We found out all the crew had been killed by an undead abomination (enemy).  The former captain (a mage) had created the abomination and wanted us to destroy it so had brought us to where it's lair was.  A cult of worshiper's has formed around the abomination thinking that he is a representation/segment of their God.

The temple they have created is on the bottom of the sea, but as was said in the question some things were changed so could see this being put at the top of a cliff.  It is perfectly balanced dome so could see magic holding together and if falling if the item was damaged.  Again, just the similarity of the derelict boats moving to a temple sounded like this module.